# PHP MVC OOP protecting views when not logged in

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, authentication

I'm new to PHP and totally fresh with OOP and MVC so please bear with me.
I built a simple login system based on a few tutorials and the outcome was satisfying enough; I can access my *controllers->actions* only if I'm logged in and if I'm not I always am redirected to the login view etc..

**Problem is:** Per example if I put in the URL *localhost/project/views/home.php* I get that view displayed. So how to protect my views if the user is not logged in?

**Code:** My *home.php* and pretty much any other view doesn't contain any interesting php code. Just minor stuff took from the *index.php*.

My *index.php*:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

define( "APP_NAME", "Edarati");

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    require_once('controllers/login_controller.php');
    require_once('models/user.php');
    $login = new LoginController();

    $login->login();

    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'register') {
        $login->register();
    }
} else {

    // logging out
    if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        if ($_GET['action'] == 'logout') {
            require_once('controllers/login_controller.php');
            require_once('models/user.php');
            $login = new LoginController();

            $login->logout();
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $controller = $_GET['controller'];
        $action     = $_GET['action'];
    } else {
        $controller = 'pages';
        $action     = 'home';
    }

    require_once('views/layout.php');
    ?>
}

If you need to see any other file or bit of code let me know!

<b>login_controller.php</b>

    <?php
    class LoginController {
        public function login() {
            require_once('views/login/login.php');
            if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
                $usr = new User;
                $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

                if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
                    $_SESSION['name'] = $usr->username;
                    header('Location:index.php');

                } else {
                    // TODO error page
                    echo "error syntaxe page teet teet"; // didnt work idk why
                }
            }
        }

        public function register() {
            require_once('views/login/register.php');
            if(isset( $_POST['register'])) {
                $usr = new User;
                $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

                if( $_POST['password'] == $_POST['conpassword'] ) {
                    echo $usr->register($_POST);
                } else {
                    echo "Password and Confirm password not match";
                }
            }
        }
        public function logout() {
            session_start();
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
```

**user.php**

```
<?php

class User {
    public $username = null;
    public $password = null;
    public $salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";

    public $first_name = null;
    public $last_name = null;

    public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
        if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
        if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
    }

    public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
        //store the parameters
        $this->__construct( $params );
    }


    public function userLogin() {
        $success = false;
        try{
            $con = Db::getInstance();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM perso WHERE login = :username AND passe = :password LIMIT 1";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            if( $valid ) {
                $success = true;
            }

            $con = null;
            return $success;
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return $success;
        }
    }

    public function register() {
        $correct = false;
        try {
            $con = Db::getInstance();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO perso(login, passe) VALUES(:username, :password)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function getUser($username) {
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $curUser = new self();

        $req = $db->query("SELECT * FROM perso WHERE login = '$username'");
        $user = $req->fetch();

        $curUser->username = $user['login'];
        $curUser->first_name = $user['prenom'];
        $curUser->last_name = $user['nom'];

        return $curUser;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Please post your `LoginController` implementation.

Comment: there you go Henrique

Comment: never heard of laravel authentication? it provides everything out of the box

Comment: Noo dynamic, do you have any specific links i can visit to get the hang of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in MVC, you want to block the direct access to your Views, and the request / response will go through the Controllers, which handles the user authentication you are talking about.

You want to render the View through the Controller only if the user is authenticated.

There are many good frameworks that will do this for you.

- [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) @dynamic mentioned
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)

Comment: So I have been exploring Laravel and Symfony, pretty useful stuff there but I need to know one thing, am I going to have to rebuild my whole website using one of them? Or is there a way to include the authentication bit in my project?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your structure. You should do something like:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    require_once('controllers/login_controller.php');
    require_once('models/user.php');
    $login = new LoginController();

    $login->login();

    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'register') {
        $login->register();
    } else {
        header('Location: /login.php');
    }
} else {
    if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        if ($_GET['action'] == 'logout') {
            require_once('controllers/login_controller.php');
            require_once('models/user.php');
            $login = new LoginController();

            $login->logout();
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $controller = $_GET['controller'];
        $action     = $_GET['action'];
    } else {
        $controller = 'pages';
        $action     = 'home';
    }

    require_once('views/layout.php');

}
```

---

Also, there is a very old bug, I was never able to really track it down, but there we go.

The way native session work in PHP is that PHP sends a cookie -- by default named `PHPSESSID` -- to the browser. The browser stores this cookie. The next request you make, your browser will send this cookie and PHP engine will interpret it and locate your session in the server, based on this session ID.

PHP might have a problem when working with sessions and using 
`header('Location:...')`.

It seems like PHP do not send that cookie because you used `header()`. This might be due some caching optimization (a delay or something).

To solve this issue, you must tell PHP that you've already finished to set your session information. This way, PHP flushes the session cookie and you can safely redirect using `header()`.

This can be done using the [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/session_write_close) function.

```
public function login() {
    require_once('views/login/login.php');
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $usr = new User;
        $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

        if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $usr->username;
            session_write_close();
            header('Location:index.php');

        } else {
            // TODO error page
            echo "error syntaxe page teet teet"; // didnt work idk why
        }
    }
}
```

Now it should work.

If anyone has more information on this bug, please comment.

Comment: No amount of setting cookies will answer the question "how to protect my views if the user is not logged in?". This doesn't seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: You right @ComputerDruid, I misunderstood the question. Added an answer to the question, but the issue I've pointed out still exists.

Comment: yes feel free to declare any other bugs. In fact I just realized that mistake Henrique and fixed it in my project, fixing the topic now too.